# display table and position absolute

Tags: css

I need the `inner` element to fill out the `outer` element? How to to it with display:table and position:absolute?

Its a must that the element with `display:table` has the following properties

```
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
```

## code

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="position">
    <div class="inner">test</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    hdksksk<br>
    kdkd<br>
    hehe
  </div>
</div>

.outer {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.position {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display:table;
}

.inner {
  display:table-cell;
  background:red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kgtd6v14/7/

Comment: Essentially you can't. An absolutely positioned element will have **no effect** on the size of it's parent. You will have to re-think your methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
.position {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:table;
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the fiddle.. The height of the parent is not specific. Have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Please try below css:

See [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kgtd6v14/4/)

CSS:

```
.outer {
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.position {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  background:red;
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the fiddle.. The height of the parent is not specific. Have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

*you said : The height of the parent is not specific*

**Change in Css:**

```
.position {
  width: 100%;<----------Added
  //More code....
}
```

**Insert Jquery:**

```
$('.inner').css('height',$('.outer').height());
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.inner').css('height',$('.outer').height());
})
```

```css
.outer {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.position {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  display:table-cell;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="position">
    <div class="inner">test</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    hdksksk<br>
    kdkd<br>
    hehe
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the fiddle.. The height of the parent is not specific. Have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I clear with question. But if I'm understand right, so try this:

```
.outer {
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.position {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display:table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  display:table-cell;
  background:red; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

your `.position` should have the same size for containing his parent `div`, and for centering your `.inner` just add this statements `vertical-align: middle` & `text-align: center`.

Comment: I made a mistake in the fiddle.. The height of the parent is not specific. Have updated my question